# How do I remove a COM+ component from a COM+ application programmatically

Tags: c#, com+, comadmin

I am trying to automate a build, and the application uses COM+ applications with Components, and I need to figure out how to delete the component from the package using c#.  I am using the COMAdmin library, and have built out a collection of the applications, but i'm kinda stuck from there.  Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

```
public static void RemoveComponents()
    {
        COMAdminCatalog objCatalog = new COMAdminCatalog();
        string ApplicationName = "Comply Plus Web";



    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'd want System.EnterpriseServices.RegistrationHelper.UninstallAssembly().